# Expressions static method requires null instance non-static method requires non-null instance

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I'm new to using Expressions and am getting the following error:

> System.ArgumentException : Static method requires null instance,
>   non-static method requires non-null instance.
>   Parameter name: method

The code is as follows:

```
        int inP = 100;
        object inParam = inP;
        Type inParamType = inParam.GetType();

        ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(S), "pe");

        Expression left = Expression.Property(pe, typeof(S).GetProperty(propName));
        Expression right = Expression.Constant(inParam, inParamType);

        MethodInfo mi = inParamType.GetMethod(operand, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, new Type[] { typeof(object) }, null);
        Expression e1 = Expression.Call(mi, left, right);
```

Answer (score 18):

You're using `BindingFlags.Instance`, so you'll only get back instance methods. Instance methods must be called as C# `a.f(b)`, not `f(a, b)`, and that translates to expression tree `Expression.Call(left, mi, right)`, not `Expression.Call(mi, left, right)`. That's what the exception is telling you:

> Static method requires null instance, non-static method requires non-null instance.

In this case you have a non-static method, therefore you must pass in an instance on which to call the method.

Comment: If I read this correctly, you're suggesting to use one of the overloads of Expression.Call that takes an instance (represented as an expression) as the first parameter.  In my case, I was able to do this by passing `Expression.Constant(instance)` to Expression.Call, as the first parameter.  Does this sound correct to you?

Comment: @RobertHarvey If the instance is not variable, for instance if you want to construct `Expression<Func<object, object>> e = a => instance.f(a);` manually, then you can in theory construct the `instance` part of that by passing `Expression.Constant(instance)` as the first argument to `Expression.Call`, but in practice, I've noticed that since the C# compiler doesn't do this (it turns it into a field in a compiler-generated class instead), some query providers don't support it, unfortunately.